# ls cmd in Mac, showing weird behaviour

Tags: macos, ls

As screenshot attached, when I do a 'ls' cmd I don't see the **project1** folder.  And 'ls -a' also doesn't reveal it.  I also ensured the file is not marked hidden in Mac.

I am not sure why the folder project1 is only shown if I do a 'ls -l', could you please help to explain?

Thank you very much

[link to screenshot](http://oi61.tinypic.com/szudr4.jpg)

Comment: Hm? In that screenshot there are five `ls` commands, each of them showing `project1`. (BTW, if it's just text, it's preferred to copy it into the question and format it with the `{}` button instead of making a screenshot.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, you're gonna kick yourself.

It's right there; it's just separated from "official_tut" by one space.

You can use `ls -F` to add a directory flag, just to help locate it.